# How do I fix this CSS display on iPhone Safari?

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, safari

It works in Chrome desktop

[image: Imgur]

But not Safari iOS

[image: Imgur]

Here is the the CSS

```
.button {
    border: 1px outset $color3;
    background: $color1;
    color: $color4;
    font-size: 80%; // A little smaller because it's in uppercase
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

I tried `font-size: smaller`, 0.8em, etc, but it did not help. 50% or 0.5em looks good on iPhone, but is too small on the desktop. `text-transform` did not matter. `padding: 1px;` did not help.

Comment: try setting display:inline-block and see what happens. Maybe add some padding as well.

Comment: Thanks `inline-block` worked! I had to fix some thing else on the sidebar as a result of that, but I was able to override and revert to `inline` for the side bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change display to inline-block, and add padding to the top